# Programatically retrieve data using iterator in oracle ADF Mobile

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I want to read programatically data using iterator in ADF mobile. My code is :

```
try {
    ValueExpression vex = AdfmfJavaUtilities.getValueExpression("#{bindings.WeatherDescriptionIterator}", Object.class);
    AmxIteratorBinding iter = (AmxIteratorBinding)vex.getValue(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getAdfELContext());
    GenericType row = null;
    BasicIterator bIter = iter.getIterator();
    iter.getIterator().first();
    ArrayList employees = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < iter.getIterator().getTotalRowCount(); i++) {
        row = (GenericType)iter.getCurrentRow();
        String phone = "";
        String email = "";
        if(row.getAttribute("Description") != null)
            phone = row.getAttribute("Description").toString();
        if(row.getAttribute("WeatherID") != null)
            email = row.getAttribute("WeatherID").toString();

        setTempValue(phone + " " + email);

        iter.getIterator().next();

    }
}
catch(Exception e1) {
    AdfException ex = new AdfException(""+e1.getLocalizedMessage(), AdfException.ERROR );
    throw ex;
}
```

I get error :-> cant not find property bindings

Answer (score 0):

the expression should be :
 ValueExpression vex = AdfmfJavaUtilities.getValueExpression("#bindings.WeatherDescriptionIterator.iteratorBinding}", Object.class);